# How do I select the actual HTML generated by knockoutjs?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Say I have the following knockout view, how can I obtain the outerHtml for the actual generated code with javascript. Whenever I try to select the outerHtml of "table_1" with javascript I end up with the html containing the knockout markup, rather than the actual HTML visible on screen.

```
<table id="table_1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: $data.Rows -->
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Date"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

Comment: You should first ask yourself why you would want to do that in the first place. Knockout is meant to manipulate the DOM and you should not write hacks around it.

Comment: But if you really wanted to do it, a quick'n'dirty solution would be to parse the whole thing with jquery, traverse every node and simply remove the `data-bind`s using `removeAttr('data-bind')`.

Comment: I need to export the html that knockout generates via javascript. The issue is that outerHtml only gets the HTML as it existed on the page BEFORE knockout manipulates it.

Comment: Oh that's different; so I assume the presence of `data-bind`is is not a problem by itself right?

Comment: Actually this works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/xjjtqr2p/2/

Comment: The `foreach` is expanded too: https://jsfiddle.net/036k92du/

Answer (score 0):

knockout components can provide the bound element.

see http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html

```
ko.components.register('printable-component', {
  viewModel: {
    createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) {
        console.log(componentInfo.element);
    }
  }
});
```

using this mechanism a 'printable' component can be developed that has access to the innerHTML of the bound element.

```js
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
  this.Rows = [{
    Name: 'Joseph',
    Date: '2017-02-13'
  }, {
    Name: 'Mary',
    Date: '2017-02-13'
  }];
}

// define a printable component
ko.components.register('printable-component', {
  viewModel: {
    // create using the factory function
    // see http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html
    createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) {

      // return a new ViewModel for the component
      return new function() {
        this.rows = params.rows;

        // track the componentInfo
        this.componentInfo = componentInfo;

        // print method function
        this.print = function() {
          alert(componentInfo.element.innerHTML);
        }
      }
    }
  },

  // the component template
  // note: can be jsx
  // note: can be defined in html using internal template nodes
  // note: print button can be hidden using CSS or by defining it outisde the printable component and use the params to start the print function
  template: '<table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Date</th></tr></thead><tbody><!-- ko foreach: $data.rows --> <tr><td data-bind="text: Name"></td><td data-bind="text: Date"></td></tr><!-- /ko --></tbody></table><a href="javascript:void();" data-bind="click:print">print</a>'
});


// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<printable-component params="rows:$data.Rows"></printable-component>
```